# PHP: Call a class from array?

Tags: php, oop, class, routes

I've just built myself a function that fetches the URI string and turns it into an array as shown below. This example is based upon the URL of `http://mydomain.com/mycontroller/mymethod/var`

```
Array
(
    [0] => mycontroller
    [1] => mymethod
    [2] => var
)
```

If I write `new $myArray[0];`, I will load the `myController` class, but can I make a function that handles the eventual existance of methods and their calling with their respective variables?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by *"handles the eventual existance of methods and their calling with their respective variables"*, but you might be after [`call_user_func_array`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php):

```
call_user_func_array(
    array($myArray[0], $myArray[1]),
    array($myArray[2])
);
```

If you want to do that for the concrete instance you created with `$controller = new $myArray(0)`, replace `$myArray[0]` with `$controller`, e.g.

```
$controller = new $myArray(0);
call_user_func_array(
    array($controller, $myArray[1]),
    array($myArray[2])
);
```

or pass `new $myArray[0]` if you dont care about the instance being lost after the call

```
call_user_func_array(
    array(new $myArray[0], $myArray[1]),
    array($myArray[2])
);
```

Otherwise you'll get an `E_STRICT` notice and cannot reference `$this` in whatever `myMethod` is. Also see the [PHP manual on possible callback formats](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback).

---

To validate the method and class actually exist, you can use

- [`method_exists` — Checks if the class method exists](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php)

Example:

```
if (method_exists($myArray[0], $myArray[1])) {
    call_user_func_array(*/ … */)
}
```

---

Please clarify your question if something else is meant. [On a sidenote, this was probably answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dynamically+call+a+class+method+php), but since I am not sure what the question is, I am also not sure which of those to pick.

Comment: this only works with static methods, else you need an instance of the class

Comment: @kemp not true, but added clarification. I think that's what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this would also work:

```
$obj = new $myArray[0];
$obj->{$myArray[1]}($myArray[2]);
```